# CSS Submenu behind parent menu

Tags: html, css, navigation

Please check this Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/5WGLs/

If you hover over `basker-holder`, you can see that it's child-> `shopping-cart` top border is not behind it's parent. It should be white. The effect I am looking for is this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBV82.png

Answer (score 1):

Simply add `position: relative;`, `background-color: #fff;` and `z-index: 2000;` to `.cart-btn`.
This way, `.cart-btn` will be over `.shopping-cart` and the `background-color` will hide to border-top.

**View exemple**: http://jsfiddle.net/5WGLs/3/

Hope this help.

Comment: Why use the extreme z-index?

Comment: Your right, I could have used a lower x-index :P But I have seen an extreme z-index somewhere, so I didn't took any chance :P

Answer (score 0):

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/B8vuk/1/)

Playing with the `z-index` and `background;` we can acheive that

edited css

```
.cart-btn {
    color: #333;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 12px;
    padding: 5px 22px;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    position: relative;
    z-index:10;
    background:#fff;
}

.shopping-cart {
    position: absolute;
    background: #FFF;
    left: 0;
    text-align: left;
    width: 160px;
    border: 1px solid #fe4365;
    top: 52px;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(25px) rotateY(50deg);
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `z-index`. [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5WGLs/4/)

But you should read [**What No One Told You About Z-Index**](http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/), because using such large z-indices is useless.